# "Attributes window" in QGIS

Tags: qgis

For some cases, I really like the ArcGIS "Attributes window". Is there something similar in QGIS?

I need to select various polygons, see in which fields all the selected polygons share the same data (and in which fields they don't) and then also change the data of some fields for all the selected polygons.

Here you see a Picture of the ArcGIS "Attributes window" [(from the ArcGIS Documentation)](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-attributes/about-editing-attributes.htm)

[image]

[Here you find a description of how attributes can be edited in the Attributes window.](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-attributes/editing-attributes-in-the-attributes-window.htm)

In the Attributes window only selected features get listed. If you select the layer instead of one feature in the attributes window, the fields get some kind of summed up. Which means, that if they all share the same value (e.g. `"Zoning – simple" = "Commercial"`) it will say `"Commercial"`. If they don't share the same value (e.g. `"OBJECTID"` or `"Shape_Length"`), the field will be empty (or say that it's not the same value, I can't remember). Now, if you change a value, it gets changed for all the selected features of the layer (which obviously doesn't work for `Shape_Length` or `Objectid`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Toggle multi edit mode](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#editing-multiple-fields) in the form view of the attribute table does, what I was looking for.

Thanks @Babel for the hint.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you are searching for the "Attribute Table" in QGIS?

Right-Click on the Layer -> Open Attribute Table

Comment: I don't think so, or at least, I didn't find the proper view of it where all the attributes of the selected features get kind of summed up in one row.

Comment: Just use « selected feature only ».

Comment: @katagena "selected feature only" does not help, since it doesn't say if a attribute of the selected features contains different values or not. Only the toggle multi edit mode does (see my answer above and step 3 of the linked documentation).

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted. This was a valid answer to how the question was originally worded.